# Hiding time in status bar

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar

Question is very straight forward

> Is it possible to hide **time** in **status bar** at **app level**?

I have seen many questions related to customizing status bars in terms of transparency, color.

I'm assuming is there something like Window.FEATURE__ for a time like below code or we should modify SystemUI and should make as System App?

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);
```

Thanks in Advance. Any links or sample code will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try with this one,

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This will hide full status bar I want only time to be hidden in status bar.

Comment: @Manju a round about way can be creating your own status bar in a full screen activity. I can't think of any other way of manipulating system level status bar.

Comment: yes you can create own status bar using linear or constraint view.

Comment: Yes. Initially I thought this the way to do but my app should handle battery, wi-fi and notifications modules internally to show their proper states. Is it really a better approach putting all modules logic inside my app  just to hide time?